# Background transparency issue

Tags: html, css, transparency, transparent

I have a problem with my "paralax" effect. I have this mockup : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWa8N.png and I want to reproduce the same with only CSS and HTML

For the first section, my background looks like this (without the text, of course): https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8lrO.png
For the second section, it's looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScBeV.png

My problem is : I want a transparency between the first slide and the second slide (the first background is not mooving, the second slide goes on top of it). But for now I just have a regular white background without any transparency..

Can you help me ?

Comment: you can just change the white background to transparent in the first image.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your div with background (or the class if you defined one)

```
.cssclass {
     background: transparent;
}
```